# How can I release the captured payment in PayPal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have block (Authorization) some amount from customer account by using the following form.

```
<form:input path="cmd" id="cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" />
<form:input path="business" id="business" name="business" type="hidden" />
<form:input path="password" id="password" name="password" type="hidden" />
<form:input path="custom" id="custom"  name="custom" type="hidden" />
<form:input path="item_name" id="item_name" name="item_name" type="hidden" />
<form:input path="amount"  id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" />
<form:input path="currency_code" id="currency_code" type="hidden"/>
<form:input path="rm"  id="rm" name="rm" type="hidden" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="${paymentForm.returnUrl}" />
<form:input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" path="paymentaction"/>
<form:input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" path="cancel_return" />
<form:input type="hidden" name="cert_id" path="certId" />
</form:form>
```

Now I want release the blocked amount. How can I do that?

Thanks In Advance

Lakshmi Priya.K

Answer (score 0):

You can either log in to the PayPal account via www.paypal.com and simply click 'Capture' on the web UI, or use our `DoCapture` API call to capture it automatically.

For details on this API call please take a look at our API docs; https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/